# Service account x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I am having issues with service accounts. I created a service account and then created .key and .crt using this guide:

https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/

I used `cluster_ca.key` and `cluster_ca.crt` from `KOPS_STATE_STORE` bucket (since I used `kops` to create the cluster) to create user `ca.crt` and `ca.key`. Then I got token from secret.

I set the context like this:

```
kubectl config set-cluster ${K8S_CLUSTER_NAME} --server="${K8S_URL}" --embed-certs=true --certificate-authority=./ca.crt
kubectl config set-credentials gitlab-telematics-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} --token="${K8S_TOKEN}"
kubectl config set-context telematics-dev-context --cluster=${K8S_CLUSTER_NAME} --user=gitlab-telematics-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
kubectl config use-context telematics-dev-context
```

When I do the deployment using that service account token I get the following error:

```
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yml": Get https://<CLUSTER_ADDRESS>/api?timeout=32s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The Service Account, Role and RoleBinding YAML:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gitlab-telematics-dev
  namespace: telematics-dev

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: telematics-dev-full-access
  namespace: telematics-dev
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
    resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods", "services"]
    verbs: ["*"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: telematics-dev-view
  namespace: telematics-dev
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab-telematics-dev
    namespace: telematics-dev
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: telematics-dev-full-access
```

The generated `kubeconfig` looks fine to me:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <REDACTED>
    server: https://<CLUSTER_ADDRESS>
  name: <CLUSTER_NAME>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: <CLUSTER_NAME>
    user: gitlab-telematics-dev
  name: telematics-dev-context
current-context: telematics-dev-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gitlab-telematics-dev
  user:
    token: <REDACTED>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. Sorry for the late answer. Posting this in case someone else is facing the same issue.

The following line is not needed:

`kubectl config set-cluster ${K8S_CLUSTER_NAME} --server="${K8S_URL}" --embed-certs=true --certificate-authority=./ca.crt`

As we are issuing tokens, only the token can be used.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help you with this case. I reproduced this on my test cluster and I can't come up with any advice other than following the step by step tutorial by Bitnami and double checking the names. I was able to successfully create the user `gitlab-telematics-dev` list pods and then create a deployment in the `telematics-dev` namespace using just your manifests and linked tutorial so the problem is not in the config or names in Roles etc. This seems to me like you had to miss something in the process.

What I can advice is to first try the commands as the created user. So when you will be able to list pods and create a deployment as `gitlab-telematics-dev` then your deployment should also work.